# reading local .owl file using Jena response filenotfoundexception

Tags: rdf, jena

I'm doing a Jena development.

When I read local files, even though it only had three lines, I could not get it functioned normally.

Here is my code :

```
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
model.read(owlPath, null);
Iterator<OntClass> it = model.listClasses();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    OntClass ontclass = it.next();
    System.out.println(ontclass.getLabel(null));
}
```

The `owlpath` value is like `file:\\animals-rdf.owl`, or `file:\\D:\\Eclipse\\workspace\\jena_demo\\sources\\amimal-rdf.owl`, or without the `file:\\` prefix, even when I used namespace `example.com# + filepath`, it still could pass.

The concrete error report is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.WrappedIOException:    
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \animals-rdf.owl
```

Could someone give a hand? I am totally confused why it couldn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file URI is broken. Try:

```
file:///D:/Eclipse/workspace/jena_demo/sources/animal-rdf.owl
```

AIUI that's how it should work on windows. You could also use a file input stream, which would obviate the need to construct a file URI:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("animal-rdf.owl"); // or any windows path
model.read(in, null);
in.close();
```